# What is the quickest way to compare two servers' IIS settings?

Tags: iis, comparison, environment

I am having non uniform results for applications running on two Windows 2003 Servers running IIS.  Is there a way to quickly dump IIS configurations to a file for comparison?  Are there good tools to compare two IIS servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give [Metabase Explorer](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/06/30/662.aspx) a shot as part of the IIS 6 resource kit.  You can view all the settings for multiple servers and copy/paste the results to an xls and compare there.

Comment: Thank you for the great link to go with the answer.

Comment: Direct Link:                                                          http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2006/12/iis-metabase-explorer-11

Answer (score 3):

You could use Web Deploy (http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) for that, you can point it to the server remotely (assuming you have Administrator credentials) and diff two servers to see what are the differences. You could even sync them if you wanted to so that they look the same.