# How to compare settings of two websites on one IIS7.5 server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404

I have two websites running on one server in IIS7.5 and would like to find a way to compare the settings each one has. (I see the [question has already been asked for IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029045/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-compare-two-servers-iis-settings).)

I want to do this so I can see why one website is handling HTTP 404 errors differently to the other. I am sure I've set all the options in IIS to be the same on each site. I've checked the web.config files have the same values in the `<httpErrors>` and `<customErrors>` nodes. I cannot see anything in applicationHost.config either.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess my question can be summarised as: What else do I need to look through, other than web.config and applicationHost.config? What IIS settings (specific to one or two websites) are stored outside those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! After going back into IIS and comparing the two websites again, I realised I had ASP errors set to "Custom" (instead of "Detailed") on the site that was the problem. The ASP.NET error settings matched, but not the ASP ones. The page that handled 404s was a classic ASP page copied from another site to save time.

I'm still interested to hear whether web.config and applicationHost.config are the only places where website-specific settings are stored?